# nmake - simulating eval function

Tags: macros, nested, eval, nmake

I'd like to get value of variable named $(MYVAR)_SOME_SUFFIX in the b.mak makefile.
Instead I get "b.mak(2) : fatal error U1001: syntax error : illegal character '$' in macro"

```
# ---- a.mak ----
all :
    set MYVAR=SOME_PREFIX
    nmake -f b.mak
#--- END ---

# ---- b.mak ----
all:
    @echo $($(MYVAR)_SOME_SUFFIX)
#--- END ---
```

Answer (score 2):

You can sort of do what you want with [inline files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242511(VS.60).aspx).

```
# ---- piotr1.mak ----

all :
nmake -nologo -f piotr2.mak MYVAR=BBB

#--- END ---


# ---- piotr2.mak ----

AAA_SETTING=17
BBB_SETTING=24

AVAR=$(MYVAR)_SETTING


all:
# create and invoke a temporary cmd file
    @<<myecho.cmd
@echo off
setlocal
REM insert nMAKE  macros into environment of the command
set AAA_SETTING=$(AAA_SETTING)
set BBB_SETTING=$(BBB_SETTING)
REM now echo the value of whichever env var is named by the
REM nmake macro, AVAR.
echo %$(AVAR)%
endlocal
<<

#--- END ---
```

when I run `nmake -f piotr1.mak` I get the expected value echo'd to the console: 24.