# Testing file existence in NMake

Tags: makefile, nmake

In a makefile for GNU Make I use this idiom to test whether a file exists:

```
static:
ifeq ($(wildcard $(FileName)),)
    # do something when the file doesn't exist
else
    # do something different when it does
endif
```

But it doesn't work in NMake (`fatal error U1000: syntax error : ')' missing in macro invocation`). How can I replace it? It would be perfect if the replacement works in both build systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**csharptest.net**'s answer is almost on point, but it lacks a *minuscule detail* regarding the difference in  indentation rules between commands and directives:

```
static:
!if exists($(FileName)) 
    @echo $(FileName) does exist!
#^^^ DO MIND THE INDENTATION HERE, a command shall fail otherwise!
#
!else
!error $(FileName) does not exist!
#^^^^^ !directives don't have to be indented, though.
#
!endif
```

Oddly enough, it can be either `exist` (as given in official docs) or `exists` to the same effect.

Answer (score 10):

Nmake can run preprocessor directives:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y32zxwh.aspx

The conditions can vary, but Exists() is one of them:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t2e8d78.aspx

```
!IF EXISTS(foo.txt)
```

Lastly you use a command-line, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkxa7sac.aspx

```
!IF [cmd /C IF NOT EXIST "foo.txt" exit 1]
```

Either way, this should work, using either !IF above here is full example:

```
!IF !EXISTS(foo.txt)
!ERROR Unable to locate foo.
!ELSE
!MESSAGE I Found foo!
!ENDIF
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's been used for ages like that in the DDK/WDK build process, where `build.exe` is a wrapper around an `nmake.exe`-based build process.

Answer (score 8):

Just to add to Jack Kelly's suggestion, you can do the test for existence in a CMD.EXE shell.  NMake also includes the ability to create a temporary .cmd file, and execute it.

Here's an example of the (n)makefile syntax, that I use for a "check-syntax" target.  It checks the syntax in a single C# source file, in a multi-file project, by doing a compile.

```
check-syntax :
    <<flymake-build.cmd  $(CS_SOURCE)
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set errorlevel=
for %%I in (%*) do if NOT x%%I == x$(FLYMAKE_ORIGINAL) (
   set filesToBuild=!filesToBuild! %%I
)
$(_CSC) /t:module $(LIBSREF) $(FLYMAKE_CHECK) !filesToBuild!
ENDLOCAL && exit /b %errorlevel%
<<
```

The "flymake-build.cmd" is the name of the temporary cmd file that gets created.  The double angle brackets (`<<`) denote the beginning and end of the content that goes into the temp file, before the file is executed.

The stuff *after* the filename on that first line are arguments passed to the .cmd file.  In this example, the arguments are the contents of a makefile variable called `CS_SOURCE`.  In my case this is just a list of filenames in the project.  Makefile variables will be expanded within the text for the temporary file, as well.  You can see I refer to a compiler (`_CSC`) and some other symbols.

Inside the .cmd code, you can do for loops, if statements, anything you like. It's a regular .cmd file.

If you want nmake to respond to errors (eg, terminate the build) generated by commands within the .cmd file, then you need to use the `exit /b` approach to end the cmd.

I found the documentation for this in a dark corner somewhere, so I thought I'd share it here for general elucidation. (**EDIT**: [here's the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242511%28VS.60%29.aspx).)

Comment: This is really neat, and way beyond what I did back when I tinkered with batch files (and I thought Bart's ModBoot boot disk was crazy). Perhaps you could make a separate question and answer for this information? It'd be a shame to have it disappear into another dark corner of the internet.

Comment: Hey Jack. yeah, I thought this was purty useful, too. I have cited this feature in a couple stackoverflow answers (ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801778/2813575#2813575, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745261/4118794#4118794), one of which was my own question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/2806325/48082). Those questions aren't very popular, though.  Nmake appears to be going out of style in favor of msbuild, these days.

Answer (score 2):

Do it at the shell level instead of the Makefile level. If you can rely on posix tools:

```
static:
    @if test -f $(FileName); then \
      echo something; \
    else \
      echo some other thing; \
    fi
```

Note the line continuation markers everywhere.

If you need to do this in `CMD.EXE`, then perhaps you can do similar using an `IF EXIST $(FileName) COMMAND ELSE COMMAND` construct.